# How to implement and async email verification logic?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I need to implement the following: I have a page on which user enters an email. Every time text changes, I have to check whether the user exists in a DB and based on that information, I should set the text of the button to either "Sign up" or "Sign in". The problem is, that this DB request may take a couple of seconds (the reason is irrelevant) and the API is async, so event handler will be decorated with `async`, and since mail entry may change several times, this handler will be called several times before any one will end. So I'll have concurrent API requests and then, potentially, concurrent attempts to change the button text and that may not end well. I thought of something like this:

```
private async void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    mailEntry.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    ...
        submitButton.Text = (await api.AccountExistAsync(mailEntry.Text)).IsRegistered
                            ? "Sign in"
                            : "Sign up";
    ...
    mailEntry.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
}
```

But a problem with this design, is that, say, a valid email was entered between `-= OnTextChanged` and `+= OnTextChanged`, in which case it'll never be checked.

My question is, what is the right way to implement what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the user from editing the text while you are validating? Or do you want to cancel the current request when a new one is issued?

Comment: I am sure I don't want to prevent the user from entering text, the user shouldn't be concerned with requests.

Comment: I am quite sure there are better ways of doing this validation check. and changing of the text should not matter.. can you show how you are currently checking if isValid User for example.. you should be checking this type of stuff on Submit..

Comment: @MethodMan see the edit

Comment: What is the behavior that you like to have? The old requests being canceled and not updating the UI and only the latest request being able to update the UI?

Comment: I'm not sure, but what you're saying sounds right, I think that would to. How can I cancel the pending event handler gracefully?

Comment: Does `AccountExistAsync` support cancellation?

Comment: Not that I know of, I think no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
private long requestNumber;

private async void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = mailEntry.Text;

    long myRequestNumber = ++requestNumber;

    await Task.Delay(200);

    if (requestNumber != myRequestNumber)
        return;

    var result = (await api.AccountExistAsync(text)).IsRegistered;

    if (requestNumber != myRequestNumber)
        return;

    submitButton.Text = result ? "Sign in" : "Sign up";
}
```

It maintains a `requestNumber` variable to hold the last request number which is incremented each time you change the text.

If after the `AccountExistAsync` operation completes the code discovers that the variable was changed, it will conclude that a new request has been issued, and will not update the UI.

Please note that the solution also waits 200 milliseconds before attempting to send a validation request. Although this will delay the validation operation 200 milliseconds, it will prevent too many requests to be sent, especially as the user is typing quickly. This is optional of course.

**Edit:**
I removed the use of synchronization when reading/updating `requestNumber` because such code runs in the UI thread only.

Comment: worked like charm. however I cannot quite understand why have you removed locking, isn't there a possibility for the event to be handled concurrently?

Comment: Because the code before and after the `await` (in a UI event handler) runs in the UI thread (as long as you don't do `ConfigureAwait(false)`) which is a single thread .

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze, I just realized that capturing `mailEntry.Text` at the beginning shouldn't matter because we only read its value if no new request was issued. What was the problem that caused your tests via the emulator to fail?

Comment: it was my fault, your code worked perfectly, never mind, I deleted my comment.

Comment: @downvoter, can you explain the problem with this answer?

Comment: Can I do that in MVVM style? I mean, without onChange events, using data binding?

Comment: Did you try to do it? What problems did you face?

Comment: well, the way to do it, seems to be to write a value converter, to convert Entry's Text value to Button's Text value, but the problem is that I'm not sure if this locking mechanism will work there, since I don't know how the Value Converter's `convert` method is evoked exactly. Will that work?

Comment: or, I could do following: I could write a backing property in a ViewModel, change it's value based on a entry text (using one-way data binding), implement API calling and locking logic like you suggested earlier and then bind it to button's text (using one-way data binding again). what do you think of that?